# How to a add Wordpress Menu Page (in the admin panel) with a custom link?

Tags: wordpress

I want a menu link right under the Settings one in the admin panel with a custom link. (Example: "Go to Google" with a link to google)

I've searched through the codex but couldn't find how can I link it to a custom address. All I could find was this:

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing i can think off is putting an auto redirect on the admin page.
So when the link is pressed you go to the admin page immediately sents you to the page.
Look at the php header function.